# jquery mobile page navigation alternative

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, frameworks

I love the navigation system in jquery mobile:

```
<a href="page-transitions-page.html" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">page</a>
```

(http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/transitions/)

Its very easy to use, and i like the transitions.
BUT i don't want to use jQuery mobile in my App because the last version was released over two years ago and it seems dead. Also i read that jQM has a bad perfomance.

So now I am looking for a HTML5 mobile App Framework with such an easy handling and transtions in navigation.

I looked in the Documentation from Framework7 and Ionic but I couldn't find transistions like "slide" for navigation...

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I hope following link will useful to you

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-native-transitions